# Python: Stopping a while loop from ending

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop, return, break

basically I am working on a program that would store login details to a dictionary and allow you log on and call the logged() function if your input matches with the appended login details. However, there seems to be a problem with my 2nd menu, which is the logged() function where it doesn't seem to handle any inputs and the while loop that keeps it going just breaks and it jumps back to asking for your login details again (Login details still work). When entering null input on the logged() menu, it should say "That was not a valid option, please try again.", and any expected input should call that function, but still they jump back to asking login details again. These while loops are a bit too confusing for me at the moment and have tried switching the validintro variables to True or False. Help would be appreciated.

```
vault = {}

def menu(): 
    mode = input("""Hello {}, below are the modes that you can choose from:\n
    ##########################################################################
    a) Login with username and password
    b) Register as a new user
    To select a mode, enter the corresponding letter of the mode below
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """.format(name)).strip()
    return mode

def login():
    if len(vault) > 0 : #user has to append usernames and passwords before it asks for login details
        print("Welcome to the login console")
        while True:
            username = input ("Enter Username: ") 
            if username == "":
                print("User Name Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            password = input ("Enter Password: ") 
            if password == "":
                print("Password Not entered, try again!")
                continue
            try:
                if vault[username] == password:
                    print("Username matches!")
                    print("Password matches!")
                    logged() #jumps to logged function and tells the user they are logged on
            except KeyError: #the except keyerror recognises the existence of the username and password in the list
                print("The entered username or password is not found!")

    else:
        print("You have no usernames and passwords stored!")

def register(): #example where the username is appended. Same applies for the password
    print("Please create a username and password into the password vault.\n")

    while True:
        validname = True
        while validname:
            username = input("Please enter a username you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your username must be at least 3 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not username.isalnum():
                print("Your username cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(username) < 3:
                print("Your username must be at least 3 characters long \n")
            elif len(username) > 30:
                print("Your username cannot be over 30 characters \n")
            else:
                validname = False 
        validpass = True

        while validpass:
            password = input("Please enter a password you would like to add to the password vault. NOTE: Your password must be at least 8 characters long: ").strip().lower()
            if not password.isalnum():
                print("Your password cannot be null, contain spaces or contain symbols \n")
            elif len(password) < 8:
                print("Your password must be at least 8 characters long \n")
            elif len(password) > 20:
                print("Your password cannot be over 20 characters long \n")
            else:
                validpass = False #The validpass has to be True to stay in the function, otherwise if it is false, it will execute another action, in this case the password is appended.
        vault[username] = password
        validinput = True
        while validinput:
            exit = input("\nEnter 'end' to exit or any key to continue to add more username and passwords:\n> ")
            if exit in ["end", "End", "END"]:
                return
            else:
                validinput = False
                register()
        return register

#LOGGED ONTO THE PASSWORD AND WEBSITE APP ADDING CONSOLE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def logged():
    print("You are logged in!\n")
    modea = input("""Below are the options you can choose:
    ##########################################################################\n
    1) Call test1 function
    2) Call test2 function
    3) Exit
    ##########################################################################\n
    > """).strip()
    return modea    

#Main routine
print("Welcome to the password vault program")
print("In this program you will be able to store your usernames and passwords in password vaults and view them later on.\n")
validintro = False
while not validintro:
    name = input("Hello user, what is your name?: ")
    if len(name) < 1:
        print("Please enter a name: ")
    elif len(name) > 30:
        print("Please enter a name no more than 30 characters: ")
    else:
        validintro = True
        print("Welcome to the password vault program {}.".format(name))

#The main program to run in a while loop for the program to keep on going back to the menu part of the program for more input till the user wants the program to stop
validintro = False 
while not validintro: 
        chosen_option = menu() #a custom variable is created that puts the menu function into the while loop
        validintro = False

        if chosen_option in ["a", "A"]:
            login()

        elif chosen_option in ["b", "B"]:
            register()

        else:
            print("""That was not a valid option, please try again:\n """)
            validintro = False

validintro = False 
while not validintro:        
    option = logged()
    print(option) 
    if option == "1":
        test1()

    elif option == "2":
        test2()

    elif option == "3":
        break
    else:
        print("That was not a valid option, please try again: ")
        validintro = False 

print("Goodbye")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the loop in your logged() function is that it is missing!  The logged function just prints the menu and reads the input.  It doesn't do anything else.  You'll need to add something like this.

```
def logged():
    print("You are logged in!\n")
    keeplooping = True
    while keeplooping:
        modea = input("""Below are the options you can choose:
        ##########################################################################
        1) Call test1 function
        2) Call test2 function
        3) Exit
        ##########################################################################
        > """).strip()

        if modea == "1":
            print("Run Test 1\n")
        elif modea == "2":
            print("Run Test 2\n")
        elif modea == "3":
            keeplooping = False
        else:
            print("That was not a valid option, please try again\n")
    return modea
```